# Tango sample apps on Android Studio, with Gradle

Tags: google-project-tango

Does anyone know a way to import the Java Tango samples (https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java) in Android Studio, and configuring correctly the build with Gradle ?
I've been able to import them in Android Studio, via "Import Project...", compile them and install them on the Tango tablet, but without using Gradle.
Any ideas ?﻿

Comment: Can you clarify this - are you saying that Android Studio's gradle scripts folder is empty ?  How exactly then is this getting built ? I'm not totally up on the java side of the build process, I use gradle mostly for NDK stuff  -  I did build and futz with the Java pointcloud sample without having to interact with gradle directly

Comment: Yeah, I think my question is: does anyone has already coded gradle.build files for that sample, that I could use.
I think @ArthurToenz has some interesting elements in his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a git project which already migrates the samples to Android Studio - https://github.com/briangriffey/tango-examples-java

Comment: Yes, I saw that too, I was watching the project. Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are asking for is the correct setup to let Gradle work for you.

For this you need to create a `build.gradle` file in your app's directory if the import did not do it for you. The build.gradle should look like this:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.project'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 16
    buildToolsVersion "19.1.0"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 21
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile files('libs/MyJar.jar')
}
```

With the corresponding values for SdkVersion, buildToolsVersion, minSdkVersion and targetSdkVersion.
In the "dependencies" block you can list all your jar-dependencies with :

`compile files('libs/thejar.jar')` or `compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])` if you have multiple jars.

**Secondly**, if it was not automatically created, you would need two files `settings.gradle` and `build.gradle` a the top-level of your project.

`settings.gradle` should contain:

```
include ':app'
```

assuming your app name is 'app'.

and `build.gradle` should contain:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Once you have this all in your project, you can use Build>Rebuild Project to make Gradle build the project for you.

Comment: All right, thank you very much, I don't have time to look more closely at it right now, but I will try it, and keep you updated on it.

Answer (score 1):

Just as a follow up here, Tango c examples has been migrated to Android Studio project, you should be able to import directly to Android Studio now.